# How to easily invert Upper/Lower case in common text editors?

Tags: text-editors

Are there any "common" text editors or word processors (Notepad, Wordpad, Word etc.) which allow you to invert the case of a string of text easily?

I've always thought there should be a shortcut so you can toggle the case between upper and lower, for example when you're...

> sPEEDILY TYPING AWAY LIKE uSAIN bOLT

...but don't notice the dreaded CAPS LOCK is on.
I would rather convert it with a few clicks than type it out again as:

> Speedily typing away like Usain Bolt

I keep meaning to write a macro or similar, but it never seems worth the effort at the time.

Comment: I guess you could call it "common" as its on almost every unix box out there .. vi has the "~" tilda key that performs case change.

Answer (score 3):

With the lightweight [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) or [Notepad2-mod](http://xhmikosr.github.com/notepad2-mod/), simply select the text you want to fix, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

[image: notepad2-mod invert case | Notepad2-mod 转换大小写]

Comment: Excellent, am yet to explore the Notepad2 features properly!

Answer (score 3):

For NotePad++, install the free TextFX plugin using the Plugin Manager, then highlight your text, and select these menu items.   Probably a quick macro could assign it to a hot-key.

[image]

It seems like you can even more easily highlight your text, right click and select "UPPERCASE":

[image]

Comment: I second you "NealWalters" and add: The OP asked for "invert Upper/Lower", which can be done, in your 1st image, by selecting NOT "UPPER CASE" but, 4 rows lower, "iNVERT cASE". Mon 29 May 2017 20:43:40 +0200

Comment: Users should NOT be impressed by the warning in "Notepad++ > Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager > TextFX" about a file being not correctly copied. Ignore the warning, TextFX will install and work fine. Mon 29 May 2017 20:44:10 +0200

Answer (score 2):

In Word, if you highlight the text and press Shift+F3 , it should toggle between upper and lower.

Comment: Shift+F3 in Word actually rotates between Initial Letter Case, ALL CAPS CASE and lower case. The [button on the ribbon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/izRGc.gif) provides even more options. Also, Word of course has AutoCorrect that can deal with accidental use of the Caps Lock.

Comment: @Karan the rotation only seems to include the initial letter case thing, when the highlighting includes a whole word, though granted that may be most of the time.

Comment: @Karan yes I agree, and a "single complete highlighted word" would indeed include "a whole word" and thus would involve the initial letter case thing as I mentioned, so no surprises there.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) has an Auto Correct option "Correct accidental use of cAPS LOCK key". I realize that it is not Word, Notepad, WordPad, but I guess it goes in the etc. category. Probably OpenOffice has that option too. Most likely the editors that you mentioned have similar options too, at least Word should have it, but I don't have Word here, so I can't say.

Comment: You're right, it does indeed - although I now recall turning it off because it kept undoing deliberately capitalised terms!

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite (Windows editor similar to Notepad++) has it.

[image: Image of UI]